# Summing all elements of a numpy array pair-wisely and creating a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

What is the fastest way to generate a numpy array (**A**) of size n*n from a numpy vector (**a**) with n elements, so that (i,j)th element of **A** will be equal to the sum of i'th and j'th element of **a**. As an example if I have the vector [1,2,3] I want to get [[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]]. Is there any pre-implemented function to do so?

Comment: `a[:,None]+a` assuming `a` is a 1d numpy array.

Comment: Thank you very much! It answers my question.